# How to pass dynamic form data in jmeter on re direction

Tags: forms, redirect, dynamic, webforms, jmeter

[image]whenever I navigate to the link [http://43.252.88.109:4006/BracketICT/testengine.aspx](http://http:43.252.88.109:4006/BracketICT/testengine.aspx) after starting the test from http://43.252.88.109:4006/BracketICT/?t=aZCcbzidJJKfFgrkk1RYPH0zHTl+MtTuoGeiUw0hEw48nLZUoPrfntO29VV2daEiR3cPbu25/Xf2a3Q1UMZs1tMlk3PvhYZb/aXd43cpH0Sp0Z1yTrWlkWOmJXsjTloRGTwk/LMZHkqQhW9CBVpyUsA==&uniqueID=dGdck61pZFjpiV7I05aERpx8kdvC0ymx&dev=1696661&reuse=1696661

there is a uniqueiD that is generated in the form data whenever i select any radio button and click on next. Also the next page that is generated has the same url i.e. [image][http://43.252.88.109:4006/BracketICT/testengine.aspx](http://http:43.252.88.109:4006/BracketICT/testengine.aspx) where a new question is generated and hence a new unique ID on every page on redirection.

How do i extract the uniqueID parameter everytime from form Data i.e. Dynamic in nature?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use post processors [Regular Expression Extractor](http://https:/Regular%20Expression%20Extractor) to extract the value.

1. Add the Regular Expression Extractor in the request generating the **uniqueID**.
   [image: Regular Expression Extractor Demo]
2. Add the details for the Regular Expression Extractor.
   [image: Regular Expression Extractor Details]

Here, you can check out in details the value of each field from [Regular Expression Extractor](http://https/Regular%20Expression%20Extractor)

`Regular Expression : &uniqueID=(.*?)&dev`
Check out [Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) for details.

3. (Optional) Add a Beanshell PostProcessor to check the extracted value in the logs.
   [image: Beanshell PostProcessor]

So, like this you can extract any data.

Hope, this resolves your concern.

Comment: Hi , there is no field as devid in my Form Data. Can regular expression extract form data on every page? Also, if I have to extract bean shell post processor, how can i store the value in of uniqueID in a variable?

Comment: Hi @Radhika, The value you wanted to extract was "uniqueID". Let me explain. The Regular Expression : &uniqueID=(.*?)&dev where Left Boundary :  &uniqueID= and Right Boundary = &dev and (.*?) captures the alphanumeric value dGdck61pZFjpiV7I05aERpx8kdvC0ymx which is your "uniqueID". The value of your uniqueID is stored in the variable named "uniqueID" , format to use ${uniqueID}.Yes Regular Expression can extract form data on every page. Form Data values like devid are part of URL you are requesting, you will find devid in subsquent requests. Does this resolves you question ?

Comment: I have added another image. Unique ID is highlighted in red inside of form data. Also my URL does not display uniqueID or form data.

Comment: Hi @Radikha, According to your current screenshot, your uniqueID is part of form data which is in part of Headers. This should be generated or displayed when you hit the request as a part of response and should be correctly captured by the Regular Expression Extractor method I explained above. May you provide a screenshot of your Response Headers and Response Body ?

Comment: can you provide me with your email or skype id so that i can share my screen and show you the exact problem? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Kindly check your email sir.