# How to use CSS Selector Extractor in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, extract

Following is my page code:

```
<label class='dblclick'>
<input  type='radio'  name='opt16647' value='a' class='d_TableCell toggleclick'>
```

I need to extract name='opt16647' from the above CSS using type='radio' and class='d_TableCell toggleclick' without selecting value. How do I achieve the same using CSS Selector Extractor and not JQuery extractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant selector expression would be:

```
input[type=radio][class=d_TableCell toggleclick]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
- [CSS how to target 2 attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397180/css-how-to-target-2-attributes)
- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks alot @Dmitri T. Also, can you please look into the query and help me out further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192803/how-to-pass-dynamic-form-data-in-jmeter-on-re-direction/62195484?noredirect=1#comment110031389_62195484

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 3 ways

1. Use "input[type=radio]" as CSS Selector Expression and Attribute as "name"
2. Use ".d_TableCell" as CSS Selector Expression and Attribute as "name"
3. Use ".toggleclick" as CSS Selector Expression and Attribute as "name"

Tested all 3 ways and they are working

Sample Request:
[image: Sample Request]

CSS Extractor using "input[type=radio]"
[image: Using input[type=radio]]

CSS Extractor using ".d_TableCell"
[image: Using .d_TableCell]

CSS Extractor using ".toggleclick"
[image: Using .toggleclick]

Results
[image: Debug Sampler Results]

Comment: Hi in case there are multiple radio buttons on the page, how do we use type='radio' and class='d_TableCell toggleclick' properties together?

Comment: In case there are multiple radio buttons on the page, use any of the above methods with Match number as 0. This will randomize your extraction. Also what is the specific need to use type='radio' and class='d_TableCell toggleclick' properties together?

Comment: i am looking for specific extraction and not randomized, that's the reason why i want to use two properties together. Is there a way to use two properties together?

Comment: The above answer gives for a specific extraction. In case the above solutions don't work for multiple radio buttons, please post the example in which it is not working by editing your original question or raise a new question for the same. Essentially what you might need is something like this - "input[type=radio],d_TableCell,.toggleclick" in CSS Selector Expression. However, this approach is very vague and doesn't offer any room for flexibility since you are concatenating too many elements to get the desired result while the same can be achieved using just 1 selector.

Comment: okay thankyou for your response. Can you look into the following query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192803/how-to-pass-dynamic-form-data-in-jmeter-on-re-direction/62195484?noredirect=1#comment110031389_62195484